# Export all views on a site to csv, json, spreadsheet etc

Tags: importing-exporting, views

### The Question.

How do I export a spreadsheet documenting all the views from a drupal site?

### More info:

Say you want a summary of all the views on a site, perhaps you are going to rebuild them - maybe there is some iffy php_views in there. Maybe you are simply documenting a messy site that you've inherited.

While there is support for exporting individual views to various formats it is not as easy to export a comprehensive list of all your views to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

### The Answer.

```
views_get_all_views()
```

### The Script (save this as views_summarize.php or similar):

```
<?php
$views = [
  [
    'view machine name',
    'view name',
    'view desc',
    'base table',
    'display machine name',
    'display title',
    'display plugin',
    'php field the first',
  ]
];
foreach (views_get_all_views() as $view) {
  foreach ($view->display as $display => $data) {
    $views[] = [
      // 'view machine name'
      $view->name,
      // 'view name'
      $view->human_name,
      // 'view desc'
      $view->description,
      // 'base table'
      $view->base_table,
      // 'display machine name'
      $display,
      // 'display title'
      $data->display_title,
      // 'display plugin'
      $data->display_plugin,
      // 'php value in default field'
      $view->display['default']->display_options['fields']['php']['php_value'],
    ];
  }
}
$fp = fopen('views-summary.csv', 'w');
foreach ($views as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

### Notes:

The returned $view object has properties nested within arrays and objects, make sure you shift gears accordingly in your query:

#### e.g.

```
$view->display['default']->display_options['fields']['php']['php_value'],
```

#### You can run this script with:

```
drush php-script views_summarize.php
```

#### Inspect the $view objects returned by views_get_all_views()

```
drush ev "print_r(views_get_all_views());"
```

### Alternative uses

Site documentation is a tricky task, this approach is useful when documenting any pre-existing site configuration or content like rules, contexts etc...

#### A few hours later

Refined version of above script - outputs marker to indicate presence and location of php in views - yikes!

https://gist.github.com/gl2748/313b19bce1a99e42d94f